# QGLWidget: Using setFormat() To Enable Multisampling = The Window Doesn't Close

Tags: c++, qt, events, opengl

I'm making a simple triangle in OpenGL with Qt4, and it works fine, until I use set format to enable multisampling. Here is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtOpenGL>
// gl window class
class GLWindow : public QGLWidget
{
public:
    GLWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QGLWidget(parent){}
protected:
    // ALL THE FOLLOWING FUNCTIONS ARE OVERRIDDEN FROM QGLWIDGET 
    void initializeGL()
    {
        QGLFormat newFormat = this->format();
        newFormat.setSampleBuffers(true);
        newFormat.setSamples(16);
        this->setFormat(newFormat);
    }
    void resizeGL(int w, int h)
    {
        glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }
    void paintGL()
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            glVertex2f(0, 1);
            glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
            glVertex2f(1, -1);
            glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
            glVertex2f(-1, -1);
        glEnd();
    }
};
// main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    GLWindow window;
    window.resize(640, 480);
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Before I added the format stuff in "initlializeGL", it worked fine (obviously except no multisampling).

Then, I add the format stuff and the window does not close. And when I say this I mean that it will not close when I press the "X" button on the top right corner, or it will not even close when I make a call to the window's "close()" function.

Furthermore, It makes a call to "closeEvent()" when you press the "X" button (I checked), but nothing actually closes. I tried making a call to "close()" inside my overridden "closeEvent()" function, but it did nothing.

Once again, I remove the code in "initializeGL()", and then it closes fine. So, I try to move the code I have in "initializeGL()" into the constructor. The multisampling works, and it closes when I press "X". Great! Except I get this after the window closes:

[image]

So that is that. In a nutshell:

- Everything works fine when there is no "setFormat()" related code in "initializeGL()".
- When I do put my "setFormat()" related code in "initializeGL()", the window doesn't close.
- When I put  my "setFormat()" related code in the constructor, I get the weird error shown in the above image when the window is closed;

So how to I get the window to close, while keeping multisampling enabled and without getting some dumb error after the window is closed?

EDIT: Here is the text in my .pro file

```
QT += core
QT += gui
QT += opengl

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `setFormat` from `initializeGL`, as it triggers a call to `initializeGL` itself. And since `QGLWidget::setFormat` is [obsolete](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget-obsolete.html) in Qt 4.8, you shouldn't use it at all.

So, first try calling `setFormat` from the constructor, then, if it doesn't work (or even if it works), try passing the format to the constructor of `QGLWidget` from `main()`.

Comment: Awesome, I passed format into QGLWidget's constructor and it works now! Thank you so much :D